# Persistent objects in Java BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to create huge persistent objects and then draw random images as well on BB.

Can you help me on this, how do I create huge objects.

Comment: is the goal just to be huge and consume all memory, or do you have some data to put in there?    Without more specifics, this sounds like a trojan horse payload.

Comment: I want to do a survey on device performance on BlackBerry VS Android

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, more detail would help.

If I parse your request properly, you just want to create a bunch of big objects and ensure they stick around, suggest creating suitably large arrays of `int[]` and sticking them in a `Set<int[]>` or something.

But, why?

Comment: I want to do a survey on device performance on BlackBerry VS Android

Comment: That's a laudable goal, but a microbenchmark of memory management performance will be highly suspect.  I suggest looking for scalable/stressful application workloads or time-tested benchmarks rather than a roll-your-own memory allocator.